# Angular.js Apply CSS to one element inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have the following html:

```
  <li ng-repeat="document in collection">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in document.nestedDocument">
            <input type="text" ng-model="document.nestedDocument[key]"> 
        </span>
      <quick-datepicker ng-model="myDate"></quick-datepicker>
      <button ng-click="dateFunction($index)" class="btn btn-info">SetDate</button>
  </li>
```

Now how can I apply CSS to `<quick-datepicker ng-model="myDate">` of only the index clicked?

e.g. I could run in the controller:

```
   $scope.isActive = true;
```

and add to my 'quick-datepicker' html:

```
ng-class="{true: 'active', false:'inactive'}[isActive]"
```

and have some CSS classes:

```
.active {
    color: red;
}

.inactive {
    color: black;
}
```

But this would color **all** datepicker elements inside ng-repeat. How to apply **only to the one** whose $index is clicked (meaning the index inside the "document in collection ng-repeat")?

Screenshot:

[image: screen-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that `isActive` is located on each `document` scope, this should suffice:

```
ng-class="{
    active: isActive,
    inactive: !isActive
}"
```

If `isActive` is shared between all `collection` (i.e. on higher scope level), you can set `isActive` to current `document` instance and check for equation instead of simple boolean flag:

In `dateFunction` function:

```
$scope.isActive = collection[index]
```

And `ng-class`:

```
ng-class="{
    active: isActive === document,
    inactive: isActive !== document
}"
```

Comment: It works! So the check "isActive === <Object object>" is a angular build-in functionality?

Comment: Actually, it's just an AngularJS expression. ng-class allows to bind class name to expression, which is more intuitive that {result: class}[expression] syntax.